# OpenCV svm prediction of images

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, qgis

Using the Orfeo Toolbox in Qgis, I labelled the image pixels and trained the svm and a model was generated in yaml format. What I understand, is that Qgis (Orfeo) uses OpenCV to do the machine learning.

The model is here :
[SVM model in yaml format generated by Qgis](http://pastebin.com/qeRgvkK4)

After which, I wrote a short snippet in Opencv to load the yaml model and classify(test) new images. However, this snippet fails. 
[Opencv's svm snippet](http://pastebin.com/3QUn5jwZ)

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict, file /home/john/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1919
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/john/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp:1919: error: (-215) samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F in function predict

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could someone figure out what is happening here ? I am quite lost. Btw, I am using OpenCV 3.0.

Thks.

Comment: I think that your SVM learned to use 4 variables, but you trying to get predictions on sample with 3 variables. Also look at type, seems that it demands float32. Maybe you should use Vec4f.

Comment: @Olologin : Thanks for that. I was able to run the operation successfully now.

Comment: my comment was right ?